# how can i concatenate string and variable in jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
?>
<button id="text<?php echo $i; ?>">hello </button>
<script>
var i=<?php echo $i; ?>;
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#text"+i).click(function(){
             alert("hello");
   })

})

</script>
<?php } ?>
```

If I have a varying `id` like this and I want to call it in jQuery using this code its give me no result. Where is the problem? How can I call an element like this `button`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be better to move the script out of the loop, get the buttons all at once and then bind the click event:

```php
// Create all buttons, with class "text-button"
<?php for($i=0;$i<5;$i++): ?>
  <button class="text-button" id="text<?php echo $i; ?>">hello </button>
<?php endif; ?>

<script>
// On document ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Find all buttons with class "text-button"
  $(".text-button").click(function(e) {
    alert("hello");

    // Log the clicked button
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
  })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am satisfied with @Emre's answer. And also remove `$(doucment).ready()` will solve your problem. Like this.

```
<?php
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
?>
<button id="text<?php echo $i; ?>">hello </button>
<script>
var i=<?php echo $i; ?>;
     $("#text"+i).click(function(){
             alert("hello");
   });
</script>
<?php } ?>
```